# How to display a gadget only if post has a specific label. Blogger

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogger

I want some of gadgets to be displayed only if posts have a specific label with them. Any suggestions how to make this possible in blogger.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in my opinion because blogger doesn't give full powers over blogspot sites. You can just use conditional tags to show or hide some widget or coding inside blogger template.
visit to get some helpful material about conditional tags:

http://www.bloggersentral.com/2010/08/targeting-specific-pages-with.html